# Show different content in modal when clicked on button - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a modal component that is being toggled on and off to show or hide it. This worked when I had a single button. Now however, I have multiple buttons and I would like to have different content displayed within the modal, dependent on which button I click. I am however stuck at this point. This is my code up till now:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import "./desktop.scss";
import {
  folder,
  about,
  code,
  contact,
  photos,
  cv
} from "../imageimport";
import Modal from "./modal";

function Desktop() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    {
      icon: folder,
      title: "New Folder",
      focus: false,
    },
    {
      icon: photos,
      title: "Pics",
      focus: false,
    },
    {
      icon: code,
      title: "Web Dev",
      focus: false,
    },
    {
      icon: cv,
      title: "CV",
      focus: false,
    },
    {
      icon: contact,
      title: "Contact",
      focus: false,
    },
    {
      icon: about,
      title: "About",
      focus: false,
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="desktop">
      {buttons.map((item, i) => (
        <div onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} className="desktop_items">
          <img
            className="desktop_items-icon"
            alt="amrani_webdevelopment_photo_icons"
            src={item.icon}
          ></img>
          <span className="desktop_items-title">{item.title}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
      <Modal onClose={() =>setShowModal(false)} show={showModal} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Desktop;
```

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: you can define another property for a button, say 'description'. Then pass it directly to the Modal component as a prop and render the description inside the Modal.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm rendering a list of buttons and used a common modal. How do you pass the prop from a button to a 'sibling' component?

Comment: Ok, I got a solution. I made to states: 1 to show/hide modal, the 2nd to save a prop.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got a solution. I made to states: 1 to show/hide modal, the 2nd to save a prop.

```
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [contentModal, setContentModal] = useState("");
```

The button now has two functions (setStates):

```
<div test="test" onClick={() => {setShowModal(true); setContentModal(item.title)}} className="desktop_items">
```

And gave the modal a new attribute to pass the props:

```
<Modal onClose={() =>setShowModal(false)} show={showModal} content={contentModal} />
```

Too bad I go downvotes, not very encouraging to new developers in my opinion. Anyway, this was kind of tricky because I couldn't put the modal in the map-function, otherwise it would be rendered 8 times. So I had to put it outside, which made  the modal a sibling-component instead of a child-component. Hope this thread will help other new developers in the future!

Comment: Please don't be discouraged not every issue can be resolved with a single solution and what works for some may not work for others. I personally appreciate your knowledge and taking the time to answer the question. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you had defined your button data like below,

```
   {
      icon: folder,
      title: "New Folder",
      focus: false,
      data: {
         description: "your description",
         otherProperty: "1",
      }
    },
    {
      icon: photos,
      title: "Pics",
      focus: false,
      data: {
         description: "your description 2",
         otherProperty: "2",
      }
    },
    ...
```

Define an index as a state

```
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(0);
```

Set the current data when clicking on the button

```
<div onClick={() => {setShowModal(true); setModalData(item.data)}} className="desktop_items">
```

Pass `modalData` to your sibling `Modal` component

```
<Modal onClose={() =>setShowModal(false)} show={showModal} data={modalData}/>
```